# Where is the choose emulator button in visual studio?

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

I have started learning xamarin, I installed visual studio and create an android project. But I can't find the "choose emulator" button to run.

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b60vb.png)

Here is what I want to have and try to find in my visual studio:

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYb4F.png)

My laptop has ram of 4G, when I press <kbd>F5</kbd> in my visual studio, there is an android emulator appear but it require 2G of RAM so my laptop can't not serve it. I want to change to another emulator to run but I can't find the button

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/debug-on-emulator/android-sdk-emulator/

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Right click</kbd> on the toolbar (empty part) and select `Standard`